# how load wordpress in a subdirectory without wordpress in root directory taking over

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have my production Wordpress website at `example.com.au` running from `/public_html`

I also have a standalone Wordpress site in a `/public_html/mainwp` subdirectory running [Main WP](http://www.mainwp.com).

The `.htaccess` in `/public_html` is:

```
# Begin Wordpress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# End Wordpress
```

If I try to load `example.com.au/mainwp/wp-admin`, I receive a 404 served by Wordpress at `example.com.au`

If I rename `/public_html/.htaccess` to `.htaccess.temp`, `example.com.au/mainwp/wp-admin` loads fine.

Something changed over the weekend and I can't work out what. I'm quite sure this `.htaccess` was working before the weekend.

Help appreciated.

***Update***: From Sagar's answer, I've confirmed `/public_html/mainwp/.htaccess` contains the following code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mainwp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mainwp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and previously that situation was working, but now it is not: `example.com.au/mainwp/wp-admin` delivers a 404 served by Wordpress at `example.com.au`

Comment: The install in the main folder is a multisite right?

Comment: Yes it is @McNab - a subdirectory multisite

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code in subdirectory .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For more information please check [Link](http://liquidbook.com/2014/08/installing-second-wordpress-instance-subfolder/)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it Sagar. I don't understand why, because it already had that code, followed by `.htpasswd` protection only. Restoring this original `.htaccess` did not break the `/mainwp/wp-admin`, even though `.htaccess` in the web root remained active, so I'm confused.

Comment: WordPress will normally write a .htaccess file in the installation directory, and that folder is usually the website root folder. That's why you have faced issue.

Comment: Sure. That doesn't explain what I wrote in my comment above though.

Comment: For the mainwp it is check /mainwp/.htacess and for newsite wordpress it is check /newsite/.htacess. So when we look in newsite .htacess it will call mainwp site. that's why it's break.